# sed add line (without spaces at the beginning ) after match (script using variables )

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed

Please help with spaces when script add line after searched pattern

```
$ cat test.txt 
   test    server:1 

 prod  server 1

$ cat ./check.sh 
#!/bin/bash
#
search="   test    server:1"
add="                 test        server:1000"
echo "starting"
sed -e "/${search}/a${add}" ./test.txt

$ ./check.sh 
starting
   test    server:1 
test        server:1000

 prod  server 1
```

spaces before:
                 test        server:1000 
are lost. How can I fix this?

Comment: Syntax is valid. `/pattern/a text` appends "text" in a new line after the pattern.

Comment: I found workaround.  i dding safepattern at the beging and after delete it

Comment: <pre> <code>
#!/bin/bash
#
search="   test    server:1"
add="   test        server:1000"
safestr="___________"
addn=$safestr$add
echo $addn
echo "starting"
sed -i "/${search}/a${addn}" ./test.txt
cat ./test.txt

sed -i "s/${safestr}/""/g" ./test.txt

cat ./test.txt
</code></pre>

Comment: @RoVo d'oh! You're quite right, I missed the `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the space, otherwise `sed` will ignore it because `/pattern/atext` and `/pattern/a text` and `/pattern/a       text` is interpreted the same.

Use this:

```
sed -e "/${search}/a${add// /\\ }" ./test.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is a subtle difference between the GNU extended command

> ```
> a text
> ```
>
> Appending text after a line. This is a GNU extension to the standard a command - see below for details.

in which the manual notes that

> Leading whitespace after the a command is ignored.

and the original and more portable form

> ```
> a\
> text
> ```

which does not strip leading whitespace. There are several ways to get the latter behavior in a "one-liner" e.g.

```
$ sed "/${search}/a\\${add}" ./test.txt
   test    server:1 
                 test        server:1000

 prod  server 1
```

(note the `\` needs to be escaped within double quotes) or

```
$ sed "/${search}/a"'\'"${add}" ./test.txt
   test    server:1 
                 test        server:1000

 prod  server 1
```

or

```
$ sed -e "/${search}/a\\" -e "${add}" ./test.txt
   test    server:1 
                 test        server:1000

 prod  server 1
```

(although note that the last one relies on another GNU extension, `-e`).

Comment: I also read this in the manual, but couldn't achieve the accepted result. This should be the accepted answer ;-)

Comment: @RoVo tbh I'm not sure that the "one-liner" forms above are strictly portable - probably the text to be appended should really be on a separate line like the GNU sed manual shows